# Changing hyperlinks on my Web page to use the PAT2PDF site instead of USPTO - are there copyright issues regarding third-party pages?

Tags: copyright, hyperlink

I have a Web site. On one of the pages of my site, there are two hyperlinks to USPTO (US Patent & Trademark Office) resources, among other content and hyperlinks. One of these two hyperlinks is of the form `http://patft1.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?patentnumber=XXXXXXX` and the other is of the form `http://patft1.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?patentnumber=YYYYYY` where XXXXXXX and YYYYYY are patent numbers. (Some patent numbers are six digits long instead of seven.) However, when accessed, these hyperlinks no longer lead to the specific patents.

I am considering changing the two mentioned hyperlinks to use the PAT2PDF site, meaning that both of the hyperlinks would be of the form `http://www.pat2pdf.org/pat2pdf/foo.pl?number=XXXXXXX` with the patent number in place of XXXXXXX as described [here](http://pat2pdf.org/). Over the years, I have looked at many Web sites and pages. My question is: If I have previously looked at a third-party page that has one or more hyperlinks to patents on the PAT2PDF site, can I change the USPTO links (that go to patft1.uspto.gov) on my page to use the PAT2PDF site instead of the USPTO site, without violating any copyright of the third-party page?